# Do we need to add Cucumber dependency along with Karate-core 1.4.0 version?

Tags: cucumber, karate, web-api-testing

[image]

I'm trying to create new project with Karate.I get some errors related to cucumber. Is anyone facing this with the new Karate version?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is mentioned in the release notes: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/releases/tag/v1.4.0

As far as I know, Eclipse IDE support may be affected. You can try manually adding this dependency to your `pom.xml`: `info.cukes:cucumber-java:1.2.5`

Comment: Hi, I tried to add io.cucumber:7.11.2 and I the change the main class in Debug Configurations as this io.cucumber.core.cli.Main. Though this error goes away I get many other weird errors related to cucumber. Also i doucmentation they mentioned they have removed cucumber but not mentioned to add dependency in our project.

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ.

Comment: @Meghana then that should be easy to solve, please use the official Karate plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/19232-karate

Comment: I added the IntelliJ plugin, looking good now. I guess I don't have to add the cucumber dependency if we have plugin.

Comment: @Meghana yes you don't need the cucumber dependency at all now

Comment: @PeterThomas Is there a "free" tier of the plugin?  I see the monthly subscription and "free" 30 day trial but nothing that explicitly states it's free for the syntax highlighting and scenario execution but not for the debugger and other "paid upgrade" features after 30 days.

Comment: @PBMax it is free for syntax highlighting, run config / running and formatting. I thought it is clear in the plugin description and the home page - but let me know what we can change to make it more clear: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/19232-karate

Comment: Thanks for the reply @PeterThomas.  It wasn't explicitly stated.  The word free isn't used anywhere in your description.  Or how long the "free" features last.  I was concerned that after the 30 days that my "free" version will be locked down and be asked to pay.  All I need is the ability to run one scenario at a time and keyword formatting.  It seems like some of the functionality I got used to was due to cucumber though.  I can't collapse code anymore.  That makes it easy to see how many scenarios I have.  Great work and I'm glad the threading issue got resolved!

Comment: @PBMax noted, thanks. will update the wording. about the code-collapsing, if you can submit a screenshot as an issue we can take a look. I thought this was working like the cucumber plugin: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-intellij-plugin/issues