Getting AssertionError: URIBuilder.getPathSegments after upgrading the Karate Core from 1.0.0.0 to 1.3.1
I upgraded Karate core to 1.3.1, its giving me compile time error for Java8.
Is it that I need to upgrade it to Java11?
While executing, I am getting AssertionError for:
URIBuilder.getPathSegments()LJava/util/List
I tried changing the Java version to 11, still then got the assertionerror.
Any input is appreciated

refer all release notes from the version you are upgrading from

Thanks @PeterThomas. Got the resolution from this ticket: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75941613/do-we-need-to-add-cucumber-dependency-along-with-karate-core-1-4-0-version
